# Passing custom object into another constructor

Tags: java, constructor, class-constructors

I have a custom Class `Employee`. Now in the `Customer` Class in the first construcor I want to pass a dummy employee object for the second constructor. How can I do this?

[image: Customer Class excerpt]

Comment: You have to import Employee or else it will be undefined. https://www.w3schools.com/java/ref_keyword_import.asp

Comment: Even importing the class or adding it to a package doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please ask yourself, "is a design I really want?"

You can pass it `null` or a dummy `Employee`.

```
static final Employee DUMMY_VALUE = new Employee();

public Customer(String name, int age){
    this(name, age, "", DUMMY_VALUE);
}
```